# Error: "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" using asymmetric algorithm

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, encryption

I want to encrypt and decrypt the string using asymmetric cryptographic algorithm that is I want to pass different key in encrypt and decrypt function.

My code is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "ABKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }

    Decrypt(clearText);

    return View(clearText); 
}

public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {

                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return cipherText ;
}
```

Here is the encrypt function I am sending the value using link
as follows

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Encrypt", "Home", new {@clearText="5"})">Bid Buddy</a>
```

Here I want to send different key values as shown.

Comment: Make sure `encrypt / decrypt` keys are same.

Comment: Your code is *not* using asymmetric encryption. AES is a symmetric algorithm and that means you need to use the same keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES is a symmetric block cipher. Decryption *only* works if the same key is presented as during encryption. There is no way around that.

What you additionally have is a cryptographic hash function. All hash functions have collisions, but the exploitation of those is negligible for a cryptographic hash function such as yours. So, it would be too costly to find two passprases that map to the same key (which would make it technically asymmetric).

You need to generate an public-private key pair. An option to do this is for example RSA. You would then encrypt the data with a random AES key and encrypt this AES key with the RSA public key. This is called [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: That's true..but is there any work around that we can use these function using diffident keys..

Comment: You mean different symmetric keys (AES)? By definition, no.

Comment: @SantyEssac what are you trying to do? What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Mixing up algorithms and "workarounds" are sure ways to weaken security. Hard-coded string keys are also a very bad idea.

Comment: Yes..as u can see in my code m trying to pass 2 diff keys but there m getting this error..and i got why m getting this answer has already given by you...

Comment: @SantyEssac I answered why it won't work what you are doing and provided a potential solution. It's still unclear what you are trying to achieve. This is probably an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

Your `encrpt / decrpyt` *keys* are different and that cause you getting this error.

> Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Make sure to keep the `encrpt / decrpt` *keys* are **same**.